# Sql server reporting 2014 SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, crm, ssrs-2012

report subscription for email giving error ,

```
ERROR: Error sending email. Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 64.233.166.108:25
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.EmailDeliveryProvider.EmailProvider.Deliver(Notification notification)
notification!WindowsService_4!1690!02/22/2018-15:10:26:: i INFO: Notification 581182bf-b06e-475b-adde-3729c3ce4281 completed.  Success: True, Status: Failure sending mail: Failure sending mail., DeliveryExtension: Report Server Email, Report: NA Report, Attempt 0
```

i am ugin  my gmail account for emails sending and smtp.gmail.com

hopes for your suggestion

Comment: can you share your code/design?

Comment: this is sql server SSRS report i did not code for it just enter email settings that i mentioned above like in this link you can see this link having screen shot (http://gaurangpatel.net/setting-up-email-subscriptions-in-ssrs)

Comment: Has the user that deployed the report left your organization? If so, it could be related to their AD account.